# Why do I get failed to execute user defined function error when I try to build regression model in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some code for building a linear regression model in spark. but when it come to building the model it throw: *SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (struct) => struct,values:array>)*

Here is my dataset:

```
val csv = 
ss.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").format("csv").load("/data.csv")
csv.show()
```

```
+----------+-----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
|      time|   use [kW]|gen [kW]|House overall [kW]|Dishwasher [kW]|
+----------+-----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
|1451624400|0.932833333|3.483333|            0.0333|           20.7|
|1451624401|0.934333333|3.466667|               0.0|      20.716667|
|1451624402|0.931816667|3.466667|            0.0167|           20.7|
|1451624403|    1.02205|3.483333|            0.0167|          106.9|
|1451624404|     1.1394|3.466667|          0.133333|     236.933333|
|1451624405|1.391866667|3.433333|          0.283333|         503.25|
|1451624406|1.366216667|    3.45|          0.283333|          499.4|
|1451624407|     1.4319|3.416667|              0.25|     477.866667|
|1451624408|     1.6273|3.416667|          0.183333|         447.65|
|1451624409|1.735383333|3.416667|            0.0167|         171.55|
|1451624410|1.585083333|3.416667|              0.05|           22.1|
|1451624411|1.510316667|3.433333|            0.0333|      21.966667|
|1451624412|1.459866667|    3.45|              0.05|      21.883333|
|1451624413|0.840583333|3.433333|               0.0|          20.95|
|1451624414|     0.7032|3.433333|            0.0167|      20.733333|
|1451624415|0.571883333|    3.45|               0.0|          20.65|
|1451624416|0.485733333|    3.45|            0.0167|      20.616667|
|1451624417|0.523166667|3.433333|               0.0|      20.633333|
|1451624418|     0.5362|    3.45|               0.0|      20.683333|
|1451624419|    0.53415|    3.45|            0.0167|      20.666667|
+----------+-----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
```

this lines of code also runs with no problem:

```
  val selectedCols = csv.select(csv("use [kW]").as("label"), $"gen [kW]", $"House overall [kW]")
  val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("gen [kW]","House overall [kW]")).setOutputCol("features")
  val output = assembler.transform(selectedCols).select($"label",$"features")
  output.show()
```

but when it gets to this section of my code:

```
  val model = new LinearRegression()
  val lrmodel = model.fit(output)
  val trainingSum = lrmodel.summary
  print(trainingSum.r2)
```

this error happens:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (struct<gen [kW]:double,House overall [kW]:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
```

I tested this code with another dataset but no problem has occured.
Here is the other dataset which works fine:

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|   Avg Area Income|Avg Area House Age|Avg Area Number of Rooms|Avg Area Number of Bedrooms|   Area Population|             Price|
+------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 79545.45857431678| 5.682861321615587|       7.009188142792237|                       4.09|23086.800502686456|1059033.5578701235|
| 79248.64245482568|6.0028998082752425|       6.730821019094919|                       3.09| 40173.07217364482|  1505890.91484695|
|61287.067178656784| 5.865889840310001|       8.512727430375099|                       5.13| 36882.15939970458|1058987.9878760849|
| 63345.24004622798|7.1882360945186425|       5.586728664827653|                       3.26| 34310.24283090706|1260616.8066294468|
| 59982.19722570803| 5.040554523106283|       7.839387785120487|                       4.23|26354.109472103148| 630943.4893385402|
```

I think the problem is with my dataset, but i cant figure out why its relavance with regression model and "user defined function"?